# Can't get name of uploaded file using Valum's AJAX Uploader and IE9

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

When using Valum's AJAX Uploader and IE9, you may do some backend stuff like adding the name of the file to the database. In every browser, the stock Valum's PHP script works just fine. But if you are using IE9, you will get errors when trying get the name of the file. Below is a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the qqUploadedFileXhr.php, there is a `save($path)` function. In it, there is another function called `getName()`. Replace it with the following:

```
function getName() {
    if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
        return $_GET['qqfile'];
    } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
        return $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
    }
}
```

IE9 uses $_FILES when uploading, not $_GET, so we need to check for that. So if $_FILES is set, we return the name of the file. Simple, works. Took me forever to figure out, so hopefully this helps you!